# using node.js with html

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js

Basically, I want to use this feed:

```
var feedParser = require('ortoo-feedparser')
var url = "http://iwnsvg.com/feed";

feedParser.parseUrl(url).on('article', function(article) {
          console.log('title; ', article.title);
        });
```

to show all news feeds in my HTML web page. However, I'm using node.js to run the web server at (localhost:8080). I have a separate file for the web server (index.html, style.css and client.js).

Instead of using console.log to show the news feed, I want it to appear on my webpage in my text area called `alltext` which is in the index.html, instead of it being printed to the console.

Comment: So you make an Ajax call to an endpoint that runs the code and you take the result and put it in the textarea. Or you get the server to add it when the page is served.

Comment: are you using ExpressJs as your web server?

Comment: yes, i'm using express.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it via various ways two of them are being mention below :

1. Using Sockets

   ```
   var io = require('socket-io');
   var feedParser = require('ortoo-feedparser')
   var url = "http://iwnsvg.com/feed";

   feedParser.parseUrl(url).on('article', function(article) {
     io.emit('article', article.title);
     console.log('title; ', article.title);
   });
   ```

   Now you can listen article event on webpage and display your result.
2. Now, Second way is traditional one. You have to save the feeds in DB and then use api to get all The Feeds you saved earlier in DB.

Thanks

Comment: thank you very much. how would i listen article event on the webpage? i'm new to all of this.